# SQL Server Replace Entire unknown String column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to replace the entire string of a column in SQL Server. I do not know what the exact string is. Thus, I have been unsuccessful in using "REPLACE".

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertHTML
    @html_section nvarchar(50),
    @html_content nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE html 
    SET html_content = REPLACE(html_content, '', @html_content)
    WHERE html_section = @html_section
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `replace the entire string`, just perform `UPDATE` like this:

```
go
create procedure insertHTML
    @html_section   nvarchar(50),
    @html_content   nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE html SET html_content = @html_content
    WHERE html_section = @html_section
END
```

The `replace` may work but will be slower:

```
SET html_content = REPLACE(html_content, html_content, @html_content)
```

and this is a kind of `overkill` as you just need to change a value.

Answer (score 0):

Replace is substitution of character you defined. Query above looks for value '' then replaced by your @html_content. Since you want to replace whole column value, why not use update?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to give us more to go on. Regardless, I'm guessing the HTML section might be something like HEAD or BODY. In that case, you can write a statement more like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.insertHTML
    @html_section   nvarchar(50),
    @html_content   nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE html SET html_content = 
        STUFF(html_content, 
              CHARINDEX('<' + @html_section, html_content), -- opening tag
              CHARINDEX('</' + @html_section, html_content) -- closing tag
              - CHARINDEX('<' + @html_section, html_content) -- opening tag position
              + LEN('</' + @html_section + '>') -- allow for the length of the closing tag
              @html_content)
    WHERE html_section = @html_section;
END;
```

That should find the opening and closing tags for the section and replace them with the contents that were passed as a parameter. I don't know if your incoming @html_content contains the tags or not. If it doesn't, you'd need to change the positiions that are calculated.